# Getting the NT header c++

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I'm currently trying to get the NT headers of an application just to train myself with the PE format.

I can't understand why the following code is giving me a `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` exception.

Since `e_lfanew` is the offset to the NT Header from the base address.

```
std::ifstream fichier;
fichier.open(exeFile, std::ios::binary);

//Positionner à la fin du fichier.
fichier.seekg(std::ios::end);
auto length = fichier.tellg();
fichier.seekg(std::ios::beg);

auto pData = new BYTE[static_cast<uintptr_t>(length)];

fichier.read(reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(pData), length);
fichier.close();

auto dosHeader = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(pData);

if (dosHeader->e_magic != 0x5A4D)std::cout << "[23] Getting the dosHeader failed" << std::endl;

auto ntHeader = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(pData + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

std::cout << ntHeader->Signature << std::endl;
```

So, the `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` is happening on the printing of `ntHeader->Signature`, as if `ntHeader` was a bad pointer:

> Exception levée à 0x00007FF7A9731554 dans Nt Parser.exe : 0xC0000005 : Violation d'accès lors de la lecture de l'emplacement 0x00000208B913E500.

Basically saying that it has an Access Violation on reading.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, where do you get `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`? Please quote the whole error message, don't just paraphrase it. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: [edit] your question to include that info. Comments are a bad place for that. Welcome, btw!

Comment: Did you specify binary mode when opening file stream?

Comment: Yes indeed, i did. Edited the code.

Comment: Do you expect the `Signature` to be a nul-terminated char array? Is it really? What does it look like when you inspect it in the debugger before the `cout`?

Comment: `pData + dosHeader->e_lfanew` is pointing to valid address?

Comment: @Mayur if the value of `e_lfnew` is accurate, then yes.

Comment: hmm, i see lots of return value check missing

Comment: I also see a lack of adequate error handling. Assuming every call succeeds, this code should be working fine. So presumably, there is a failure occuring somewhere that is not being caught properly. Is `open()` failing? Is `tellg` reporting a bad length? Is `read()` failing? Etc

Comment: Since the dos header is getting the correct value. The data has been readed correctly. And the NT_HEADERS is coming directly from the data + e_lfanew. So everything should be correct. But you are right i'm going to do some error handling.

Comment: Your problem seems to be specific to C++ Runtime. Because your calculation is correct. Be sure of that pData is allocated correctly. The problem may be due to that.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem myself and I found that if the pData pointer is larger than `0x00000000ffffffff` only the eight least significant bits remain after the addition: `pData + payloadDosHeader->e_lfanew`.

I'm not sure why this is the case but by casting `pData` to a `long long` this can be avoided.

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)pData;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((long long)pData + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
```

Or

```
auto dosHeader = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(pData);
auto ntHeaders = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>((long long)pData + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
```